# how to ensure that user select different comobox option in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have gridview with a combo box column Named ColumnLocationDemo. I want to ensure that user every time selected distinct option from comobox. i am trying this code message box appearing but dont know how to change the index of columnLocationDemo?? there is not selectedIndex property in this gvCombobox

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string str1 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                string str = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                if (str==str1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("same occur");
                    ColumnLocationDemo
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...
Don't use the currentRow. Just compare the new value with the values already selected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;j++ )
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = "";
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`columnLocationDemo.SelectedIndex = 0;`

If that is the name of your comboBox. Also you can select any index.

Comment: columnLocationDemo is the name of the comboBox?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //your work;
}
```

Comment: what is this i want logic?

Comment: which work i need to do please look my problem i have gridview with a combo box column Named ColumnLocationDemo. I want to ensure that user every time selected distinct option from comobox. i am trying this code message box appearing but dont know how to change the index of columnLocationDemo